# How to create <Integer, Character> in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

At the end of the day, i'd like to do

```
NSDictionary *nodeData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:numbers forKeys:characters];
```

where `numbers` is an `NSArray` of numbers and `characters` is `NSArray` of characters.

I suspect i can always do

```
NSMutableArray *numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[numbers addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:12]];
[numbers addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:23]];
[numbers addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:45]];
```

As for characters .. i am not sure. Is this ok?

```
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[characters addObject:@"a"];
[characters addObject:@"b"];
```

**Questions:**

- How to wrap up a character into an object class?
- Is there a way to add a bunch of integers at once without wrapping each one into NSNumber's alloc init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- The easiest way to box a character is to box it in an `NString` as you did.

2- The easiest way to box a integer is to write:

```
NSNumber *myIntBox = [NSNumber numberWithInt:8];
```

1bis- You can also box a character in a `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumber *myCharBox = [NSNumber numberWithChar:'c'];
```

The shortest way to initialize a dictionary with such constants is something like:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"a", 
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"b",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"c",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], @"d",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], @"e",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], @"f",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:7], @"g",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:8], @"h",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:9], @"i",
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:10],@"j", 
                    nil];
```

Comment: Thank you Jean-Denis. Good stuff

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding `object` to array that is `object` is automatically `retained`, so in your case you have got memory leak. The best approach is to add `autoreleased` `object` if you will use its value in another place. For example:

```
[numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12]];
```

> Is there a way to add a bunch of integers at once without wrapping each one into NSNumber's alloc init?

Yes, it is. You can use c-style coding:

```
int *array = (int*)calloc(sizeof_array, sizeof(int));
array[0] = 12;
array[23] = 23;
// using your array
free(array);
```

In such a way you can store characters too:

```
unsigned char *carray = (unsigned char*)calloc(sizeof_array, sizeof(unsigned char));
carray[0] = 'a';
carray[23] = 'b';
// using your array
free(carray);
```

Comment: Well, your C array will not play nice with an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Well, it is obvious that you can map your characters to numbers very quickly and easily with C-array.